# How to retain type of geom column as geometry and not text while using aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql

This is the test table and data

```
test
id;geom

INSERT INTO public.test(1, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((2 2,1 3,2 4,3 3,2 2))'));
```

and when I do query I get geom type as `text` but I want it as original type `geometry`

```
select max(geom) as g from public.test
```

`ST_GeomFromText` doesn't work here.

Comment: What do you expect as a maximum of geometries?

Comment: based on area of geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX(geometry)` is not defined because you have many possible criteria to choose the max, e.g.:

- northern-most point
- largest polygone area (works only for closed polygons)
- largest polygone length
- ...

So, PostGIS interprets `MAX()` only on text representation. For more other criteria, you have to calculate this criterion explicitly.

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=744f760c437930f1d034a2bfd53dc34a)

If you want to order the geometries by their polygon area, you have to calculate the area with `st_area()`

```
SELECT
    data,
    st_area(data)
FROM t
```

Afterwards you can filter the record with `max(area)` either with `ORDER` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
    data,
    st_area(data)
FROM t
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

or with a subselect

```
SELECT
    data
FROM t
WHERE st_area(data) = (
    SELECT max(st_area(data)) FROM t
)
```

Comment: indeed order by will help here.